# RegEx How to find text between two strings

Tags: regex

I have this text and I want to capture

```
begin
text 
end

begin
text 
end

begin
text 
end
```

the text between the begin and end.

```
/begin.*end/
```

this will capture the first begin and the last end.

Answer (score 13):

Make it lazy - `/begin.*?end/`

Sidenote: "lazy" is no less acceptable than "non-greedy" is. [Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification), [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx), [example](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)

Comment: The term is "non greedy" (not "lazy")

Answer (score 4):

If your text contains line feeds (`\n` or `\r`) you'll need to add the "dotall" flag to your regex, as well as make your match *reluctant* (ie "non greedy")

Depending on your regex flavour:

```regex
/begin.*?end/s
(?s)begin.*?end
```

Comment: js version; `/begin.*?end/s` [doesn't work in regex101 ](https://regex101.com/r/HzsPk7/1) while [python version](https://regex101.com/r/zsq4IQ/1) does. I tried whit scaped `\s` but no matches.

Comment: @Mike of course `/begin.*?end/s` doesn't work in regex 101, because the forward slashes are not part of the regex. They are delimiters in js, but people frequently include them in js-related regex answers because that's how you code them (ie slashes instead of quotes, and flag after the regex also delimited by slashes). It's akin to coding the non js version with quotes in an answer, like `"(?s)begin.*?end"` (which people also sometimes do too).