# Php : regular expression to find a text between strings

Tags: php, cookies, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx How to find text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360686/regex-how-to-find-text-between-two-strings)

I am new to REGEX and learning..this is emergency and some one need to help me,
how can i get a value 6Lf4 (dynamic value) ,

```
 private="key" value="6Lf4" sent="yut"
```

P.s there are lots of attribitute named **"Value"** in an string, so i need some regex to find string between `="key" value="` , and `"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work given a strict format:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/="key" value="([^"]*)"/', $inputString, $matches);
```

This tests specifically for the given format with no exceptions. If there is a variable amount of whitespace between `"key"` and `value`, you can change the regex to have `key"\s+value` instead.