# How to use htmlspecialchars only on <code></code> tags.

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm using `WordPress` and would like to create a function that applies the PHP function `htmlspecialchars` only to code contained between `<code></code>` tags. I appreciate this may be fairly simple but I'm new to PHP and can't find any references on how to do this.

So far I have the following:

```
function FilterCodeOnSave( $content, $post_id ) {
    return htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_NOQUOTES);
}
```

Obviously the above is very simple and performs htmlspecialchars on the entire content of my page. I need to limit the function to only apply to the HTML between code tags (there may be multiple code tags on each page).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Use regular expression to extrapolate your intended block.

[/start.*?end/][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360686/regex-how-to-find-text-between-two-strings

Comment: @NeilMasters — HTML tags are not simple strings, they can have attributes, white space, are case insensitive… http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: @Quentin The good old adage that you cause more problems with regex than it solves :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: updated to avoid multiple CODE tags

Try this:

```
<?php

// test data
$textToScan = "Hi <code>test12</code><br>
    Line 2 <code><br>
    Test <b>Bold</b><br></code><br>
    Test
    ";

// debug:
echo $textToScan . "<hr>";


// the regex pattern (case insensitive & multiline
$search = "~<code>(.*?)</code>~is";

// first look for all CODE tags and their content
preg_match_all($search, $textToScan, $matches);
//print_r($matches);

// now replace all the CODE tags and their content with a htmlspecialchars() content
foreach($matches[1] as $match){
    $replace = htmlspecialchars($match);
    // now replace the previously found CODE block
    $textToScan = str_replace($match, $replace, $textToScan);
}

// output result
echo $textToScan;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much closer to what I'm looking for. I've now got a problem that on each save of my post, the <code></code> tags are duplicated, so after 3 saves i have 3 sets of code tags in a row <code><code><code>code content here</code></code></code>. Any idea why this might be happening or how I can avoid it?

Comment: I updated the answer. It's not generating multiple code tags now. 
Instead of generating `&gt;code&lt;` it's leaving the `<code>` tags in place. Is that what you wanted? If yes, please accept the answer.

Comment: Very nice ... But it can't handle `<code> <code></code> </code>`

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get all <code> tags;

```
// in this example $dom is an instance of DOMDocument
$code_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('code');

if ($code_tags) {
    foreach ($code_tags as $node) {
        // [...]
    }
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Could you post a full explanation of this? I tried it using `$dom=new DOMDocument();` then `$dom->loadHTML('<div>Hey<code> </div> </code></div>')'` ... But `$dom->textContent` is empty ...

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a little bit late, but you can call the [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function first and then when outputting call the [htmlspecialchars_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) function