# How to match all characters (as few as possible) between two strings?

Tags: regex, comments, pascal

I am trying to write a regex that matches a comment that begins with a `(*` and ends at the first occurence of a `*)`

`(* comment *)`

From other posts on stack overflow about matching between parenthesis I put together the following regex.

`\(\*(([^*\)])*)\*\)`

This works as long as there are no `*` or `)` characters within the comment. However, I want to allow these characters in a comment as long as they are not next to each other.

The following are all valid comments.

`(*****)`

`(*()*)`

`(*)(*()**)`

And a notable invalid comment is

`(*)`

I tried some stuff using lookaheads but to no avail. A pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx How to find text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360686/regex-how-to-find-text-between-two-strings)

Comment: Please state the regexpression engine you use. Sorokin's? The one packages with newer Delphi's ?

Comment: Can't you just use `\(\*(.*)\*\)`? Or is that too naive?

Comment: @Marco can we close this duplicate question?

Comment: @mickmackusa: voted.

Comment: I didn't vote for duplicate because Delphi specific regex engines are often more limited, and a specific question can be on topic. The question is abandoned, not duplicate IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

match any string which contain an open parentheses followed by any characters any numbers of times followed by a closing parenthesis

```
\(\*.+\*\)
```

Comment: But `(**)` is a valid (but empty) comment too, so why not just `\(\*(.*)\*\)`? The `(.*)` part captures the content of the comment.